# Why does C# not complain about compiling this line of code

Tags: c#

```
  string json = "{ "Name": "Tom" }";
  var regex = new Regex(@"\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})");
  json = regex.Replace(json, match => char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
```

The variable "match" is not defined in my code. The code executes without problem but I'd like to know why C# does not complain that it is undefined? Right after this code, if I write:

```
x = 1;
```

C# will complain that x is not defined. What's going on?

Comment: The `match =>` is the declaration.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Did you ever heard of Lambda expressions?

Comment: Compiling is the 2nd part, first how is it not giving error on `match.Groups[1].Value` code if it is not defined?

Comment: btw; you would be well-advised to use a JSON parser here; JSON is not a "regular" language, so will have most of the pitfalls that impact html: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/23354

Comment: @MarcGravell Normally that is true, but not in this case. The real json data I deal with contains javascript hex literals: \x2c, etc. The json parser cannot handle that. But that's a different issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `match` is declaring the parameter - therefore `match` is perfectly well-defined *inside the lambda*. Essentially (since this is compiling to a delegate), this is all syntactic sugar for something very similar to:

```
static string HazNoName(Match match)
{
    return char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value,
         System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
}
//...
json = regex.Replace(json, new MatchEvaluator(HazNoName));
```

(although actually the C# compiler will cache and re-use the delegate instance in this case, since there is no captured context)

Comment: Ok. Never heard of Lambda expressions. The => is what threw me off. I should have recognized that this was not the same thing as >=.

Answer (score 0):

`match` is a parameter in the lambda expression, why should the compiler complain?

[Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)